# Java String Task

Tags: java, string

I have such a problem, I wrote the code and it is almost correct, but it incorrectly considers the situation when in the String
"qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqfunfunfwewewewewewqwyeqet" I need to find the positions and number of occurrences of the string "funf".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s = scan.nextLine();
        String s1 = scan.nextLine();

        Main main = new Main();
        int howManyTimes = main.calculation(s, s1);
        System.out.println(howManyTimes);

        int position = -1;
        while ((position = findNextWordPosition(s, s1, position + 1)) != -1) {
            System.out.println(position + 1);
        }
    }

    public int calculation(String s, String s1) {

        int howManyTimes = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - s1.length() + 1; i++) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < s1.length() && s1.charAt(j) == s.charAt(i+j); j++) {
                counter++;
            }
            if (s1.length() == counter) {
                howManyTimes++;
            }
        }
        return howManyTimes;
    }
    static int findNextWordPosition(String s, String s1, int startIndex) {
        if (s.isEmpty() || s1.isEmpty() || startIndex < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        int position = s.indexOf(s1, startIndex);

        return position;
    }
}
```

My code handles this situation incorrectly, please help.

Comment: You didn't explain what you need to do

Comment: Your code looks ok, it should print 2 for the string input you provided, and also print correct indexes.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I'm trying to solve a problem and my code passes all tests except this:

Input:

qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqfunfunfwewewewewewqwyeqetweweutqeyqtiwteyurewrererwreeruiouuuieuyoweyuiyuihjknbsbdgfuirghbuhfjlvfhiorhgldfjhfoihjfhdhiihhhfhoihoirehghfhofjhvhrruuuhrhurhuhuhfghfdsjfghfghdfghdfgdfhgjdfhjgheodfhdfbjhtubdjbndfjhgdfjhfjhgfdjghfkjfdhueighfdjk
funf

Output:

1
17

And my code output is

2
17
20

Comment: You should update your question with the exact problematic input, the expected output, and an explanation of what the expected output means.

Answer (score 0):

> *'... I need to find the positions and number of occurrences of the string "funf". ...'*

Utilize the *[String#indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,int))* method.

Here is an example.

```java
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
int i = -1;
while ((i = s.indexOf("funf", ++i)) != -1) l.add(i);
```